# Stylus passing iteration variables to mixin argument

Tags: css, stylus

Im struggling with setting for loop variables to a mixin.

```
for num in (1..3)
  &.item{num}
    sprite($sprite-item{num})
```

It does not work. An error occurs in the 3rd line giving "num" to sprite() mixin.

The below is successfully compiled, but does not work as expected cuz the given argument is a string, not a variable. How do you configure dynamic variables in for loop iteration???

```
for num in (1..3)
  &.item{num}
    sprite('$sprite-item' + num)
```

Without the loop function, the code will be

```
&.item1
    sprite($sprite-item1)
&.item2
    sprite($sprite-item2)
&.item3
    sprite($sprite-item3)
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first assumption when looking at the code (before getting to your problem) was that usually when dealing with lists or arrays, the first term would be in position 0... And so on.  Hence instead of saying **1-3**, I would think it would be **0-2**.  Try:

```
for num in (0..2)
    &.item{num}
        sprite($sprite-item{num})
```

This is just an educated guess however because I don't have enough information to really take a look.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!

    for num in (1..3)
        &.item{num}
            sprite('$sprite-item' + num)

The above seems working. But another issue..
The variables "$sprite-item1", "$sprite-item2", and "$sprite-item3" are not regarded as variables, but strings..

Answer (score 0):

Stylus doesn't support variables interpolation, but you can use [lookup](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#lookupname) bif for this task. For example:

```
for num in (1..3)
  &.item{num}
    sprite(lookup('$sprite-item' + num))
```